# Make new windows always open in specific monitor by default

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, window-manager

Ubuntu 18.04.2 x86_64

I have a dual monitor setup. The behaviour for opening a new window is very inconsistent among applications and it's annoying:

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Firefox seems to always open a new window, maximized, in the monitor where my mouse cursor is.
- Likewise, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Terminal app opens a new, non-maximized window in the same display as my mouse cursor.
- Starting `gvim` from `zsh` in `tmux` in the Terminal app:

  - The new window sometimes opens on my primary display, sometimes on my secondary display;
  - The new window is sometimes maximized, sometimes not.

The inconsistency and unpredictability is very annoying. Is there a way to fix that? I basically want all new windows to open on my secondary display by default, regardless of the position of my mouse cursor or of my currently focused window. I'm undecided whether I want the new windows to always open maximized. Having them consistently default to my secondary display would already be a huge improvement.

**EDIT**

The "Workspaces on primary display only" option had always been enabled in `gnome-tweaks` by default. So I just tried the "Auto Move Window" extension for GNOME. The extension introduces weirdnesses of its own, e.g. I tried configuring the extension to always open the Terminal app in workspace 2, and this is the behaviour I get:

- If my mouse cursor is on the *primary* display (which should be workspace 1), then when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in the Terminal app, the new window is nowhere to be found. I suspect it's because it's still trying to follow my mouse cursor, but the mouse cursor is outside the displayable area of workspace 2.
- If my mouse cursor is on the *secondary* display (which should be automatically workspace 2), then when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in the Terminal app, the new window is opened *beneath* the current Terminal window and not focused, which is annoying in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

There are gnome extensions that can help:

- [Auto Move](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/) applications to specific workspaces when they create windows.
- [Smart Auto Move](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4736/smart-auto-move/) learns the size and position of your application windows and restores them to the correct place on subsequent launches. Supports Wayland.
- [Moves panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4890/move-panel/) to secondary monitor on startup, without changing the primary display. Only works on Wayland.